# Real world situation with System of Equation with 3 variables?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, matrices, systems-of-equations, applications

Where do you run into a real world situation involving 3 variables and 3 equations?  Can someone think of a specific example from business, etc?  I recall taking an operations research course that seemed to involve optimization of 3 variables, but do not recall a single example or theme.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are wondering if a model with 3 variables seems like overkill, you should consider that "real world situations" involve a HUGE number of variables, but they are typically assumed to be constant for the sake of a manageable model.

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of Christmas and New Years' resolutions, suppose that what we were on a diet and needed to eat precisely $245$ calories, $6$ grams of protein, and $7$ grams of fat for breakfast. Unfortunately, I open my cupboard to see that all I have is three boxes of cereal: Cheerios, Cinnamon Toast Crunch, and Rice Krispies. There nutritional information per serving is as follows:

```
Cereal                     Calories     Protein     Fat
Cheerios                   120          4           2
Cinnamon Toast Crunch      130          3           5
Rice Krispies              105          1           2
```

Now, normally, I would dive in and gorge myself on Cinnamon Toast Crunch$^\dagger$ because they're delicious - but, I need to stick to my new years resolution.

First, I denote $c = $ servings of cheerios, $t = $ servings of Cinnamon Toast Crunch, and $r = $ servings of Rice Krispies. Then, I form the following system of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns:

$$120c + 130t + 105r = 245 \ \text{calories}$$
$$4c + 3t + r = 6 \ \text{grams of protein} $$
$$2c + 5t + 2r = 7 \ \text{grams of fat} $$

Now, I leave it to you to find out if I am stuck with one bland mix of cereal$^1$, whether I will be able to form many mixtures of cereal$^2$, or If I will be forever cursed with the dreaded stomach-tire$^3$.

$^1$The system has a unique solution.

$^2$The system has infinitely many solutions

$^3$The system has no solution

$^\dagger$French Toast Crunch is **even better**, and baby [it's back](http://time.com/3623148/french-toast-crunch/).

Note: I got the numbers for this (silly) example from [here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~dk/math40/math40-lect03.pdf), courtesy of Dr. Dagan Karp.

Comment: Gabriel, thanks, and don't take this the wrong way, but this is a perfect example of a fake contrived textbook problem.  In which universe will you ever have this fake constraint of precisely 245 calories, 6 grams of protein, and 7 grams of fat?  I am hoping to find a real example that makes sense, not a fake example that is created strictly to justify the math.  You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

A few examples that may or may not arise in other answers...

- When you have a set of data of the form $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ and you want to fit a model of the form

$$z=a\,f(x,y)+b\,g(x,y)+c,$$

least squares leaves you with three equations in $a$, $b$ and $c$.

- Any kind of a 'network flow'. For example suppose that you have a roundabout with three exits and the flow in and out of each exit is known then using the principle that the flow into a junction should equal the flow out leaves you with three equations in the unknown flow between exists.
- When doing a partial fraction expansion --- which occurs in various applications --- you are often left with simultaneous equations.

Answer (score 0):

Linear programming.  look [HERE](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/linprog4.htm) ... in fact the first example (rabbit food) involves three variables.